# Поиск слова заданной длины

Tags: массивы, c++

Спарсил исходный код страницы. На всю разметку пофиг. Нужно вычленить слова длинной, допустим 7 символов, в которых первая буква Н.

Из языка разметки пусть тоже берутся такие слова. 
Пока опустим усложнения, пускай это будут цифры. В любой кодировке ведь тоже самое? Если нет, то пусть будет UTF8.
Как то так.

Comment: Тут основной вопрос в том, что именно Вы называете словом и сомволом (зависит от кодировки, может ли она меняться внутри страницы, как это отслеживать...) и кучи других мелочей, которые Вы не описали.

Comment: Нет, на разметку как раз _не_ пофиг. Комментарии, текст на js, inline css Александр Сергеевич за вас фильтровать будет?

Comment: @Korts: Ещё раз: дайте строгое определение того, что вы считаете словом. Если последовательность цифр, игнорируя разметку, задача несложная: начали с начала текста, в цикле по символам

* пропустили всё до первой цифры. если при этом встретился конец текста, финиш, иначе запомнили позицию.
* пропустили всё до первой не-цифры, запомнили позицию
* между двумя позициями очередное слово
* перешли к следующей итерации цикла

Перед началом работы раскодируйте текст так, чтобы символы были одинаковой ширины (в UCS-2 или UCS-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если отвлечься от условностей, которые начинаются странным словом "спарсил" и заканчиваются  кодировкой (будем считать, что речь идёт про us-ascii), то задача сводится к следующей:

> Выделить из строки все слова длиной не
> менее N символов. Словом считать
> последовательность цифр, все остальные
> символы - разделители.

OK, пишем на C - просто для разжёвывания алгоритма по шагам:

```
static int
is_valid_char( char c )
{
    /* только цифры, можно было бы и isdigit(), но для наглядности */
    return (int)strchr( "0123456789", c );
}

static void
store_word( char * word )
{
    /* просто выводим и освобождаем память */
    printf( "%s\n", word );
    free( word );
}

size_t
find_words( const char * s, size_t min_length )
{
    size_t words_found = 0;
    size_t word_length;
    const char * end = s;
    const char * start;

    while( *end )
    {
        while( *end && !is_valid_char( *end ) ) end++;
        start = end;

        while( *end && is_valid_char( *end ) ) end++;
        word_length = end - start;

        if( word_length >= min_length )
        {
            char * word = (char *)malloc( word_length + 1 );
            memcpy( word, start, word_length );
            word[word_length] = 0;
            store_word( word );
            words_found++;
        }
    }
    return words_found;
}
```

Проверяем:

```
int 
main()
{
    return printf( "words found: %u\n", find_words( "1234 567 56a78988", 4 ) ) == EOF;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1234
78988
words found: 2
```